# How to Execute two services sequential using c# automation framework(Using technologies C#, NUnit, Specflow)

Tags: c#, wcf, nunit, specflow

I have two automation projects in c#, which includes two services automation scenarios. 
1.  Export Service: it generates files that need to be translated by other service.
2.  Translation Service : it will translate files generated by above service.

I need help how I can run test scenarios of both services sequentially means export services scenarios will execute first then after Translation Service scenarios will execute. Please help on this . Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChannelFactory class and synchronous calls:

```
    public static void MakeSequentialCalls1()
    {
        var fact = new ChannelFactory<IFileProcessor>("processorEndpoint");
        var processorProxy = fact.CreateChannel();

        var fact2 = new ChannelFactory<IFileTranslator>("translatorEndpoint");
        var translatorProxy = fact2.CreateChannel();

        var file = processorProxy.GetFile();
        var translatedFile = translatorProxy.Translate(file, "En");

        ProcessResult(translatedFile);

        ((IClientChannel)processorProxy).Close();
        ((IClientChannel)translatorProxy).Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like scenario 2 should include the scenario 1 steps or a shorthand step for performing scenario 1.